# Delete all lines except the one that matches a pattern and also keep 2 lines before the match

Tags: vim

Is it possible in vim to delete all the lines except for the ones that match a pattern and also keep a couple of lines before and after (like a context in grep).

Comment: Could you add a "before/after" sample, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you mentioned grep, the cleanest way is probably to simply invoke `grep` on the whole buffer.

```
%!grep -2 pattern_to_match
```

I will update if I find a pure-vim solution, but I doubt it will be cleaner than the above solution.

Comment: What does the -2 flag do?

Comment: @SylvesterVLowell, It is the context option that the OP mentioned. Basically it tells grep to display two lines before and two lines after the match.

Answer (score 4):

Another pure-vim solution that copies the output to a register:

```
:redir @a
:g/pat/z.5
:redir END
```

Command `:z.5` works like grep -2. Check help about it - it can be used for some interesting effects.

Command `redir @a` redirects output to register `a`, and `redir END` ends redirection.

But if you just want to see the found lines with some context, then `:g/pat/z.5` might be your best option.

Answer (score 3):

A pure vim solution using `:global`

```
:let @a=""
:g/pat/-2,+2y A
:%d_
:pu a
:1,2d_
```

Overview:

Yank 2 lines on each side of the pattern and append to a register. Then delete the buffer and replace with the contents of the register.

Note: Use @merlin2011's grep version. It is the simplest.

For more help see:

```
:h :range
:h :let-@
:h :g
:h quote
:h :d
:h :pu
:h registers
```